# Yii - Unabled to log in

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, yii

Sorry, this is a really newbie question. I'm following the blog tutorial from the official site, and I have my code like [in this snippet](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1655230/). After I made the changes, hitting login only goes to a blank page. Other pages are still accessible, but they still show that I'm not logged in. Any input is appreciated :)

[login.php snippet](http://fpaste.org/Bujn/) and [siteController.php snippet](http://fpaste.org/1Dyv/)

Angela

Comment: Snippets have been updated. Please let me know if I need to provide anything else :)

Comment: Could you post your `protected/components/UserIdentity.php`

Answer (score 0):

There may be many factors, so let's try these for a start:

1) set `'enableClientValidation'=>false,` in login.php

2) Add in line 81 of your site controller:

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
```

Comment: Sorry, where should I add the second line in SiteController.php?